# iOS store and access images

Tags: ios, image, nsdictionary

My application downloads user information and profile pictures from my server when a user opens another users profile. 
I am using a `NSDictionary` to store each object of my `User` class (with `NSCoding`), filled with the info from the server, with key being the users unique id. 
This works perfectly fine for example, when a user opens another profile i request its version first, compare it locally and if the servers version for this profile is higher, i request the user info. Same goes for the profile picture.
At the moment i am storing the users profile picture as `NSData` in the `User` object.
`@property (nonatomic, copy) NSData *profileImg;`

But i think this is not a good solution since the `NSDictionary` could grow in size very fast and this could lead to long loading times.

What could be a good solution to this problem? I need to store the images separately, i think, so i can access them fast.
Should i save them to the documents directory? Or use Core Data?
I know this is not a question that can be answered with code, i was just wondering what the best solution might be.